# @aws-sdk/lib-storage to Stream JSON from MongoDB to S3 with JSONStream.stringify()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm trying to Stream JSON from MongoDB to S3 with the new version of @aws-sdk/lib-storage:

```
"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.17.0"
"@aws-sdk/lib-storage": "^3.34.0"
"JSONStream": "^1.3.5",
```

Try #1: It seems that I'm not using JSONStream.stringify() correctly:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { Upload } from '@aws-sdk/lib-storage';
const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: env.AWS_REGION });

export const uploadMongoStreamToS3 = async (connectionString, collectionName) => {
  let client;

  try {
    client = await MongoClient.connect(connectionString);
    const db = client.db();
    const readStream = db.collection(collectionName).find('{}').limit(5).stream();
    readStream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify());
 
    const upload = new Upload({
      client: s3Client,
      params: {
        Bucket: 'test-bucket',
        Key: 'extracted-data/benda_mongo.json',
        Body: readStream,
      },
    });
    
    await upload.done(); 
  }
  catch (err) {
    log.error(err);
    throw err.name;
  }
  finally {
    if (client) {
      client.close();
    }
  }

};
```

Error #1:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of
> type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object.
> Received type object
> at Function.from (buffer.js:305:9)
> at getDataReadable (/.../node_modules/@aws-sdk/lib-storage/src/chunks/getDataReadable.ts:6:18)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
> at Object.getChunkStream (/.../node_modules/@aws-sdk/lib-storage/src/chunks/getChunkStream.ts:17:20)
> at Upload.__doConcurrentUpload (/.../node_modules/@aws-sdk/lib-storage/src/Upload.ts:121:22)
> at async Promise.all (index 0)
> at Upload.__doMultipartUpload (/.../node_modules/@aws-sdk/lib-storage/src/Upload.ts:196:5)
> at Upload.done (/.../node_modules/@aws-sdk/lib-storage/src/Upload.ts:88:12)

Try #2, using the variable `jsonStream`:

```
  const readStream = db.collection(collectionName).find('{}').limit(5).stream();
    const jsonStream = readStream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify());
 
    const upload = new Upload({
      client: s3Client,
      params: {
        Bucket: 'test-bucket',
        Key: 'extracted-data/benda_mongo.json',
        Body: jsonStream,
      },
    });
```

Error #2:

> ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined
> at Object.getChunk (/.../node_modules/@aws-sdk/lib-storage/src/chunker.ts:22:30)
> at Upload.__doMultipartUpload (/.../node_modules/@aws-sdk/lib-storage/src/Upload.ts:187:24)
> at Upload.done (/.../node_modules/@aws-sdk/lib-storage/src/Upload.ts:88:37)

Try #3: use `stream.PassThrough`:

```
    client = await MongoClient.connect(connectionString);
    const db = client.db();
    const readStream = db.collection(collectionName).find('{}').limit(5).stream();
    readStream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(uploadStreamFile('benda_mongo.json'));

...

const stream = require('stream');
export const uploadStreamFile = async(fileName) => {
  try{

    const pass = new stream.PassThrough();
    const upload = new Upload({
      client: s3Client,
      params: {
        Bucket: 'test-bucket',
        Key: 'extracted-data/benda_mongo.json',
        Body: pass,
      },
    });
    const res = await upload.done();
    
    log.info('finished uploading file', fileName);
    return res;
  }
  catch(err){
    return;
  }
};
```

Error #3:

> 'dest.on is not a function at Stream.pipe (internal/streams/legacy.js:30:8'

Try #4: mongodb.stream({transform: doc => JSON.stringify...}) instead of JSONStream:

```
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { Upload } from '@aws-sdk/lib-storage';
import { env } from '../../../env';
const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: env.AWS_REGION });

export const uploadMongoStreamToS3 = async (connectionString, collectionName) => {
  let client;

  try {
    client = await MongoClient.connect(connectionString);
    const db = client.db();
    const readStream = db.collection(collectionName)
      .find('{}')
      .limit(5)
      .stream({ transform: doc => JSON.stringify(doc) + '\n' });
  
    const upload = new Upload({
      client: s3Client,
      params: {
        Bucket: 'test-bucket',
        Key: 'extracted-data/benda_mongo.json',
        Body: readStream,
      },
    });
  
    await upload.done(); 
  }
  catch (err) {
    log.error('waaaaa', err);
    throw err.name;
  }
  finally {
    if (client) {
      client.close();
    }
  }
};
```

Error: #4:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of
> type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object.
> Received type object
> at Function.from (buffer.js:305:9)
> at getDataReadable (/.../node_modules/@aws-sdk/lib-storage/src/chunks/getDataReadable.ts:6:18)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
> at Object.getChunkStream (/.../node_modules/@aws-sdk/lib-storage/src/chunks/getChunkStream.ts:17:20)
> at Upload.__doConcurrentUpload (/.../node_modules/@aws-sdk/lib-storage/src/Upload.ts:121:22)
> at async Promise.all (index 0)
> at Upload.__doMultipartUpload (/.../node_modules/@aws-sdk/lib-storage/src/Upload.ts:196:5)
> at Upload.done (/.../node_modules/@aws-sdk/lib-storage/src/Upload.ts:88:12)

Try #5: using `stream.PassThrough()` and return `pass` to `pipe`:

```
export const uploadMongoStreamToS3 = async (connectionString, collectionName) => {
  let client;

  try {
    client = await MongoClient.connect(connectionString);
    const db = client.db();
    const readStream = db.collection(collectionName).find('{}').limit(5).stream({ transform: doc => JSON.stringify(doc) + '\n' });
    readStream.pipe(uploadStreamFile());
  }
  catch (err) {
    log.error('waaaaa', err);
    throw err.name;
  }
  finally {
    if (client) {
      client.close();
    }
  }
};


const stream = require('stream');

export const uploadStreamFile = async() => {
  try{
    const pass = new stream.PassThrough();
    const upload = new Upload({
      client: s3Client,
      params: {
        Bucket: 'test-bucket',
        Key: 'extracted-data/benda_mongo.json',
        Body: pass,
      },
    });
    await upload.done();
    return pass;
  }
  catch(err){
    log.error('pawoooooo', err);
    return;
  }
};
```

Error #5:

> TypeError: dest.on is not a function
> at Cursor.pipe (_stream_readable.js:680:8)

Comment: Thanks but got the same error. I succeeded to pipe to a fs.createWriteStream and write to a file, later I can use fs.createReadStream and pipe it to my 'uploadStreamFile' and it will work. but I don't like this solution as it causing my server to write to a temp file instead of streaming the mongoDb res to s3 directly.

Comment: Thanks, the full stacktrace is: 'dest.on is not a function
      at Stream.pipe (internal/streams/legacy.js:30:8'

Comment: I've updated the question with all relevant error messages

Comment: I removed the comments as they are already included in the answer. I hope that any of the proposed alternatives work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing your error stack traces, probably the problem has to do with the fact that the MongoDB driver [provides a cursor in object mode](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/cursor/#stream-api) whereas the `Body` parameter of `Upload` requires a *traditional* stream, suitable for be processed by `Buffer` in this case.

Taking your original code as reference, you can try providing a `Transform` stream for dealing with both requirements.

Please, consider for instance the following code:

```
import { Transform } from 'stream';
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { Upload } from '@aws-sdk/lib-storage';
const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: env.AWS_REGION });

export const uploadMongoStreamToS3 = async (connectionString, collectionName) => {
  let client;

  try {
    client = await MongoClient.connect(connectionString);
    const db = client.db();
    const readStream = db.collection(collectionName).find('{}').limit(5).stream();
    // We are creating here a Transform to adapt both sides
    const toJSONTransform = new Transform({
      writableObjectMode: true,
      transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        this.push(JSON.stringify(chunk) + '\n');
        callback();  
      }  
    });

    readStream.pipe(toJSONTransform);
 
    const upload = new Upload({
      client: s3Client,
      params: {
        Bucket: 'test-bucket',
        Key: 'extracted-data/benda_mongo.json',
        Body: toJSONTransform,
      },
    });
    
    await upload.done(); 
  }
  catch (err) {
    log.error(err);
    throw err.name;
  }
  finally {
    if (client) {
      client.close();
    }
  }

};
```

In the code, in `toJSONTransform` we are defining the writable part of the stream as object mode; in contrast, the readable part will be suitable for being read from the S3 `Upload` method... at least, I hope so.

Regarding the second error you reported, the one related with `dest.on`, I initially thought, and I wrote you about the possibility, that the error was motivated because in `uploadStreamFile` you are returning a `Promise`, not a stream, and you are passing that `Promise` to the `pipe` method, which requires a stream, basically that you returned the wrong variable. But I didn't realize that you are trying passing the `PassThrough` stream as a param to the `Upload` method: please, be aware that this stream doesn't contain any information because you are not passing any information to it, the contents of the readable stream obtained from the MongoDB query are never passed to the callback nor the `Upload` itself.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too. Running the code with syntax of: 'Body: readStream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()),' will return the following error: '  ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined'

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. Please, can you provide further information about the error stack trace in the question? I think it can be of relevance.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question with all relevant error messages

Comment: Thank you very much @OronBen-David. I updated the answer with further alternatives. Regarding `ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined` I think it has to do with the fact that the stream obtained with `JSONStream.stringify` is only writable in our use case, but not readable at the same time: I think I misunderstood the library documentation which states that it can be both writable and readable, like a transform, but I am afraid that not at the same time. The error makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, I added #4-#5 tries information to the question

Comment: Thank you very much @OronBen-David. I tried providing further possibilities: according to the stack traces you provided, the proposed solution can be an option. I am not sure if it would work, but please, can you try?

Comment: Thank you! It works! Your code manages to upload objects one after the other but not within an array. I'm happy to update you that I was able to find a solution using stream.PassThrough, I will post it in the next few minutes

Comment: That is great @OronBen-David. I am very happy to hear that it worked properly. Thank you vey much for sharing the `stream.PassThrough` based solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

I found additional solution using `stream.PassThrough`, using JSONStream will stream array of objects instead of one after the other:

```
export const uploadMongoStreamToS3 = async (connectionString, collectionName) => {
  let client;

  try {
    client = await MongoClient.connect(connectionString);
    const db = client.db();
    const passThroughStream = new stream.PassThrough();
    const readStream = db.collection(collectionName)
      .find('{}')
      .stream();

    readStream.on('end', () => passThroughStream.end());

    readStream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(passThroughStream);
    await uploadStreamFile('benda_mongo.json', passThroughStream);
  }
  catch (err) {
    log.error(err);
    throw err.name;
  }
  finally {
    if (client) {
      client.close();
    }
  }
};


export const uploadStreamFile = async(fileName, stream) => {
  try{
    log.info('start uploading file', fileName);
    const upload = new Upload({
      client: s3Client,
      params: {
        Bucket: 'test-bucket',
        Key: `${fileName}`,
        Body: stream,
      },
    });

    const res = await upload.done();
    log.info('finished uploading file', fileName);
    return res;
  }
  catch(err){
    log.error(err);
    return;
  }
};
```